# Matlab: use variable with different index in loop

Tags: matlab, loops, indexing

I have big data files with currents and voltages. I measure several times my devices but the number of measurements varies. I first ask the user how many rounds of measurements there are, after which I make a loop to extract the currents from the data. My current variables are arrays of 200x3000 doubles. I call them for example Isd_round1, Isd_round2, etc...

```
for i=1:rounds_number
    [filename,pathname]=uigetfile('*.mat', 'Select matlab data');
    pathname = cd(pathname);
    pathname = strcat(pathname, '\', filename);
    Val=load(pathname);
    assignin('base', ['Isd1_round' num2str(i)], Val.Isd1)

    ...etc...

end
```

After that, I want to plot and compare the currents, but I cannot seem to find a way to call the variables by changing the index. I would like to do something like this:

```
figure
hold on
for j=1:rounds_number
    plot(V, Isd_roundj)
end
```

And I don't know how to call the variables by changing the index in the loop.

I could also do an array of all the currents but as each current is already an array of (n, m) doubles, how can I create a variable "current" where I would assign "Isd_round1" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Name variable based on string MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017859/name-variable-based-on-string-matlab)

Comment: Don't do this. Use a cell array to hold your data rather than using `assignin`.

Comment: I asked at the end of the post how I should do this. As every current is already an array of 200x3000 doubles, how should I creat an array of arrays?

Comment: I just said it. A cell array. `Isd1_round{i} = val.Isd1`

Comment: @Blackcal Yes, `Isd(:,:,round) = Val.Isd1`.

Comment: @Blackcal Do this ^^ if they are all guaranteed to be the same size

Comment: Or a cell array :) I like using normal arrays when possible (i.e. when all of the sub-arrays are the same size).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a cell array to store the data, as was mentioned before. Here is some example code how, to do this:

```
dataCell = cell(rounds_number,1)
% read data in
for i=1:rounds_number
        [filename,pathname]=uigetfile('*.mat', 'Select matlab data');
        pathname = cd(pathname);
        pathname = strcat(pathname, '\', filename);
        Val=load(pathname);
        dataCell{i} =Val
end

%plot
for i=1:rounds_number
        plot(dataCell{i})
end

%quicker, warning this plots all rounds at once
cellfun(@(x) plot(x),dataCell)
```